# Изъяснительное или определительное придаточное?

Tags: придаточное-предложение

Не могу разобрать, как определить тип **придаточного**.

Что посеешь, то и пожнешь. Пожнешь (что), что посеешь. Или так: пожнешь то (какое), что посеешь? Второй вариант выглядит странным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Местоименно-определительное** придаточное, нет изъяснительного значения:

***Что** посеешь, **то** и пожнешь.*

Местоименная пара: ***ТО...ЧТО,*** инверсия. Местоимение ***ТО*** роли определяемого слова (**дополнения**).

**Вопросы:**

То (**какое именно?**) пожнешь, что (= которое) посеешь.

Comment: очень странный вопрос. а почему не от сказуемого?

Comment: А почему должно быть от сказуемого?

Comment: я думаю, что более логично задавать от сказуемого.

Comment: Я так не думаю. Мы определяем дополнение, а не сказуемое.

Comment: Инверсия — это когда меняешь местами придаточное и главное? Где, кроме этого, в русском языке еще применим термин «инверсия»?

Comment: Думаю, что это изменение обычного порядка слов. Например, дополнение стоит после сказуемого, а его можно поставить перед сказуемым.  С определениями тоже самое.  Норма: согл. определение перед  существительным, а несогл. – после сущ.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна  Пусть вопрос кажется странным или корявым, всё дело в заложенном смысле и грамматике:  Пожнёшь (что?) **то** (что именно? какое оно? что это?), **что** посеешь. Изъяснительным здесь и не пахнет. :)) **Что** здесь не союз.